# How to use SparkSQL Function inside DataFrame Where/Filter condition?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark. For example, I have a simple DataFrame `"df"` with 1 column `"Col1"` which contains lots of blank spaces as below:

```
Col1
"  - "
"abc "
"  xy"
```

I want to take all the rows that are not "-" after `trim`. In SQL it's simple:

```
select Col1 from df where trim(Col1) <> "-"
```

Result

```
abc  
  xy
```

I don't want to use SQL statements here, so I tried both

```
df.where(trim(df.Col1) <> "-").show() 
and
df.filter(df.Col1.trim() <> "-").show()
```

But both did't succeed, it said that `trim` isn't an attribute of a `DataFrame`, when I read the Document Trim Function is in Function Page, not DataFrame Page. I don't want to use `withColumn` since I still want to keep the format of my old column. Also transform into SQL Statement Query isn't good since I still have lots of Df functions to use after this.

So how do I do this simple condition checking with `Spark DataFrame`?

Comment: use the [`trim()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.trim.html#pyspark-sql-functions-trim) function

Comment: `df.filter(F.trim("Col1") != "-").show()`

Comment: Oh, turn out I forgot to import the trim() function. Should have used from pyspark.sql import * instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct syntax:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
data = [("  - ",), ("abc ",), (" xy",)]
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(["value"])
df.where(f.trim(f.col("value")) != "-").show()
```

output:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
| abc |
|   xy|
+-----+
```

The `<>` operator is for SQL syntax, the equivalent in this scenario is `!=`